# Trying to create a GUI for one of my projects and keeps bringing back this error?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

Working on a Sudoku solver using backtracking in Python and building a GUI for it but it keeps coming up with these three errors:

```
DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __ int __ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  pygame.draw.line(win, (0,0,0), (0, i*gap), (self.width, i*gap), thick)

DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __ int __ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  pygame.draw.line(win, (0, 0, 0), (i * gap, 0), (i * gap, self.height), thick)

DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __ int __ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  win.blit(text, (x + (gap/2 - text.get_width()/2), y + (gap/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Please, remember to make proper use of code formatting tools, and also consider adding your code to the question, as it's makes a lot easier to trace the problem and propose a solution, consider reading this guide about how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Some of the parameters you are passing are probably `float`. Do `int(var)`. For example, do

`pygame.draw.line(win, (0, 0, 0), int(i * gap, 0), int(i * gap, self.height), thick)`

In python, you can do a division with the operator `//` to apply int to the results. So you can do:
`win.blit(text, (x + (gap//2 - text.get_width()//2), y + (gap//2 - text.get_height()//2)))`

Comment: It looks like your int() calls are in the wrong place with too many arguments.